# What are the differences between JQuery Inview.js, wow.js and waypoints.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am little new to web designing. I have seen a lot of websites which use either inview.js, wow.js and waypoints.js. I have studied about that plugins in their websites and github, but I can't understand how they are different exactly and when to use them. **All I want is to reveal some animations when a div is in the viewport.** **And that must be mobile friendly.** If you can give some information about those differences, similarities, browser supports and when to use those plugins, it would be a great help.

Thank you in advance..!

Comment: There are thousands of plugins and libraries out in the wild. Asking for comparisons and recommendations is off topic here. Doing research, documentation etc is often as time consuming as actually writing code. Pick one who's features do what you want and that is well documented. Checking any repo activity can also be helpful sometimes

Comment: Like said, jQuery community produces thousands of plugins, you may find many of them similar to each other in terms of functionality, but each plugin has its own way of implementation. Anyway, you can use any of the mentioned plugins for your purpose. Personally I use wow.js and combine it with animate.css to produce realtime animation